# Is there a way increase text size in Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, display, screen, terminal

> Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

I am currently running a Raspberry Pi on a television and the text size is too small to read. So I was wondering if there is a way to resize the text.

Comment: Use HDMI if at all possible, this allows the raspberry to detect the actual size of a pixel

Comment: Can you please accept one of the answers? Only accepting an answer will finish your question and it will not pop up again and again, also after 8 years now.

Answer (score 16):

## Console

Run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

and follow the on screen instructions.

Answer (score 6):

If it's the console, you can change the `framebuffer_width` and 
`framebuffer_height values` in `/boot/config.txt`. Similarly, for X, you can set the `hdmi_group` and `hdmi_mode`, though they aren't so obviously easy to change.

Comment: It's a horrible idea to set the resolution via `/boot/config.txt`.

Comment: @BryanDunsmore Why do you say that? Its how it's supposed to be done on the Pi.

Comment: Raspbian comes with an exquisitely-commented `/boot/config.txt` for that very purpose. The method is also described in Halfacree and Upton's book [Meet the Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1680 "Meet the Raspberry Pi"). So I think it's legit ...

Comment: @Jivings Sorry about that. I confused `/boot/config.txt` with something else. =/

Answer (score 4):

You can use variations of the setfont command to change the font and the size of text:

```
setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/Lat15-TerminusBold20x10.psf.gz
```

And you can obviously see what fonts are available by doing:

```
ls /usr/share/consolefonts
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about just giving a link before to my site. Didn't mean to offend. Anyway to write a permanent script that can be run at boot-up on large-screen T.V.s, I did the following: However, there are probably a million ways to do this. The above should work too, this is just a different approach. Also, it's fun to write scripts, right?

1)The first step is to log in

2)If your in the terminal already, great. bonus points for bravery. If not, press 
CTRL+ALT+F1 to get there.

3)create a directory to put your scripts in:

`sudo mkdir /home/pi/scrpits`

4) Navigate to that directory:

`cd /home/pi/scripts/`

5) Using either vim or nano, or pico, or whatever your favorite terminal text editor is, create a new file for the script. For convenience sake and because it’s already installed, we’ll use nano here, however I prefer vim. If you want to install vim, type:

`sudo apt-get install vim`

Otherwise, use nano:

`sudo nano largefont`

6) Write this in the file:

`#!/bin/bash
echo changing font size to 32x16
setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/Lat15-TerminusBold32x16.psf.gz`

7) Make it executable:

`sudo chmod 775 largefont`

8) Now, we need to alter some files in /etc/rc.local, where Raspberry Pi goes to look for scripts or commands for start-up, and type the following:
sudo nano /etc/rc.local

9) Go yo the bottom and type the following:

`sudo /home/pi/scripts/largefont`

If you want to make it sleep until your log in appears, and run it in the background you can adjust the sleep like this. The ampersand makes it run in the background BTW:

`sudo (sleep 3; sudo /home/pi/scripts/largefont) &`

10) When you reboot, the text size should be much larger than factory settings:

`sudo reboot`

Hope this tutorial helped with something! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes - there is a fudge solution - use pixel doubling. It worked of me using a TV and 1920x1080 'resolution' - it appeared to make everything larger so I could read the menu options.

It's in (menu) top LHS raspberry:  /preferences / raspberryPi configuration/   (systems tab - last entry).

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to *Start button > Preferences > Appearance Settings > System Tab*
2. Click on *Font* and pick a size. You can even change the font family, if you want.

Doesn't work for some software, but it does apply to the system.